# Translating Object Position following Sine Wave in Javascript to and fro Motion

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made program in javascript  in which div translates it's Position from left to right following the Sine Wave.
Here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <head>
        <title>Move Object</title>
        <style>
            #field {position: relative;height: 300px;background-color: lightgreen;}
            #ball{ position: absolute;left: 0;bottom: 50%;width: 1em;height: 1em;border-radius: 0.5em;}
            #ball { background: red; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>     
        <div id="field">
            <div id="ball"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

                var field = document.getElementById("field");
                var ball = document.getElementById("ball");
                var maxX = field.clientWidth - ball.offsetWidth;
                var maxY = field.clientHeight - ball.offsetHeight;
                var duration = 5; // seconds
                var gridSize = 50; // pixels
                var start = null;

                function step(timestamp){ 
                    var progress, x, y;
                    if(start === null) start = timestamp;
                    progress = (timestamp - start) / duration / 1000; // percent

                    x = progress * maxX/gridSize; // x = ƒ(t)
                    y = 2 * Math.sin(x); // y = ƒ(x)

                    ball.style.left  = Math.min(maxX, gridSize * x) + "px";
                    ball.style.bottom = maxY/2 + (gridSize * y) + "px";
                    if(progress >= 1) 
                    {   
                        start=null;
                    }
                    requestAnimationFrame(step);
                }
                requestAnimationFrame(step);
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Division is Translating from left to right but I want to trace back the motion from right to left to and fro.
Can anyone Help Me to Sort this Problem ??

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate trough domain of a function in discrete steps by going from lowest to highest member of the domain of your function. Do the opposite, start at last member of the domain (you already calculated that as mmayX) and decrease it from that discrete step till you reach lowest one.

If this sounds complicated, here is 1 liner fix that might explain it better:

```
x =  maxX/gridSize - (progress * maxX/gridSize);
```

Change that and voila:

[demo fiddle of dot going backward](https://jsfiddle.net/yw6nbbkw/)